# Is it path- connected or not?

Tags: general-topology

i have this set $E=\{a,b,c\}$ with this topology $\tau=\{E,\emptyset, \{a\},\{a,b\}\}$

I have to show if $E$ is path-connected or not ?

I have to construct a continuous function between a and b, b and c , a and c.

1) between a and b:
$\varphi_1: [0,1]\rightarrow E, \varphi_1(t)=a, 0\leq t<1, \varphi_1(1)=b$

$\varphi_1^{-1}(\{a\})=[0,1[=[0,1]\cap]-1,1[$(is open ), $\varphi_1^{-1}(\{a,b\})=[0,1]$, $\varphi_1^{-1}(\emptyset)=\emptyset$ and $\varphi_1(E)=[0,1]$

2) between c and b: if i suppose that $\varphi_2: [0,1]\rightarrow E, \varphi_2(t)=c,0\leq t<1, \varphi(1)=b $ then we have $\varphi_2^{-1}(\{a,b\})=\{1\}$ it is closed.

So i think that the set is not path-connected, no ?

Edit 1: If i choose $\varphi_2(t)=b, 0\leq t<1, \varphi_2(1)=c$ then i have :

$\varphi_2^{-1}(\{a\})=\emptyset, \varphi_2^{-1}(\{a,b\})=[0,1[, \varphi_2^{-1}=\emptyset, \varphi_2^{-1}(E)=[0,1]$

Thank you

Comment: You've shown ONE such function doesn't work.  You need to show that no such function exists  (or use a theorem about path connected spaces)

Comment: Do you mean $\varphi_1^{-1}(\{a\})=[0,1)?$

Comment: Ah so if i choose $\varphi_2(t)=b, 0\leq t<1, \varphi_2(1)=c$ it works

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: What about $\varphi_2: [0,1]\rightarrow E, \varphi_2(t)=b,0\leq t<1, \varphi(1)=c$?

Answer (score 1):

> 1) between a and b:
>   $\varphi_1: [0,1]\rightarrow E, \varphi_1(t)=a, 0\leq t<1, \varphi_1(1)=b$

This is indeed continuous.

> 2) between c and b: if i suppose that $\varphi_2: [0,1]\rightarrow E, \varphi_2(t)=c,0\leq t<1, \varphi(1)=b $ then we have $\varphi_2^{-1}(\{a,b\})=\{1\}$ it is closed.

First, let's be clear: closed doesn't imply not open. However, $\{1\}$ is not open, so this is not a continuous map.

But what if we used this instead: Let $\varphi: [0,1]\rightarrow E$ such that 
$$
\varphi(t)
 =
\left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       a : & t<0.5 \\
       b : & 0.5\leq t<1 \\
       c : & t=1
     \end{array}
\right.
$$

Wouldn't this be a continuous map?

Comment: this map can be used to prove the three cases ?

Comment: It depends on your specific characterization of path continuous, but essentially yes, provided you can prove it is continuous.

Comment: what do you mean by : It depends on your specific characterization of path continuous

Comment: there exists a continuous map $\varphi:[0,1]\rightarrow E$ continuous with $\varphi(0)=x, \varphi(1)=y$ that is our definition

Comment: You can define the same mathematical concept using different definitions. What definition did your professor give you?

If your definition is some variation on "for every two points, there exists a continuous map from the interval to the space which maps onto those two points", then yes, proving my function is continuous is sufficient.

Comment: there exists a continuous map $\varphi:[0,1]\rightarrow E$ continuous with $\varphi(0)=x, \varphi(1)=y$

Comment: I think you mean $\varphi(0)=x$ and $\varphi(1)=y$. But in that case, you'll need to tweak my function, since $b$ isn't mapped to by either $0$ or $1$.

Comment: so if i want a path between a and c your example is good if i want a path between a and b i must chage the place between b and c

Comment: @Vrouvrou: The map is a continuous surjection from $[0,1]$ to $E$. If you know that the continuous image of a path-connected space is again path-connected, then this can be used here.